# Help me getting my system preferences to work again

Tags: system-settings, big-sur

Since the previous update (the one before BigSur), my system preferences were terrible slow. Since the update to BigSur, the systempref's stopped working at all.

The error says: "**Preferences error** The 'x' preference pane cannot be loaded"

[image]

This happens on all preference panes, [here is a video](https://youtu.be/j0xR257qVT8) explaining the problem.

I've tried

- SMC reset (putting off, disconnecting cable for a while, reconnecting and restarting)
- PRAM + NVRAM reset (shut down, hold option, cmd + P + R)
- Deleted the systemprefs .plist file and restarted

Nothing worked so far, I can't connect my bluetooth mouse, headphones, and all the other settings. Can some one help me out with this issue?

**-Update-**
Okay, I guess I somehow found the error...
I logged in to the new account again. And look at this...
https://youtu.be/kapOvWY8xXE

When I go to the apple icon in the top left corner, it gives me another version of systemprefs. When I go to the systemprefs trough the applicationsfolder, I've got the 'new' systemprefs witch works as it should... The question now is, how can I override the 'old' systemprefs with the 'new' in the top-menu.

Comment: If you create a new user account on your Mac, can you open System Preferences there?

Comment: Thanks @nohillside for your response. I've made a new user (trough terminal), but it has the same problem.

Comment: User-supplied preference panes can be found in `/Library/PreferencePanes/` and `~/Library/PreferencePanes/`. As the problem seems to be system-wide, start by temporarily moving all folders in `/Library/PreferencePanes/` to another place and try again.

Comment: Also, please have a look at `/var/log/system.log` at a point in time you tried to access preference panes, maybe it gives a clue. I somehow suspect access right/permission issues

Comment: @nohillside Hmm, both folders are empty... maby thats the issue?
Let me take a look at the log. Thanks for your help so far! :)

Comment: @nohillside 

hugo com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.com.apple.systempreferences.12888829348.12888829355(501)> [1012]
hugo com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.09000000-0700-0000-0000-000000000000[33310]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[91]

Comment: hugo SharingPrefsExtension[34173]: objc[34173]: Class PDFToRasterImageRef is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPSharing.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/SharingPrefsExtension.appex/Contents/MacOS/SharingPrefsExtension. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Empty is fine, it just means you never installed any pref panes (it also matches your screenshot).

Comment: I have the same messages in the log, so this doesn't give us any clues. Hmm.

Comment: Let's see which files get accessed before the error. Open System Preferences, then open a Terminal window, run `sudo fs_usage -f filesys "System Preferences"` there and then click on any Pane. Curious what the output is in Terminal.

Comment: (PS: The command reports all filesystem related system calls done by Preferences)

Comment: @nohillside Thanks man for your time. The output is the following https://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads9/5fece74a8a271/5fece74a83470-Schermafbeelding_2020-12-30_om_21.45.10.png

Comment: Might be worth a try to quit System Preferences and run `rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.systempreferences.savedState`. It's a long shot though, as it's unlikely that it got corrupted on several user accounts.

Comment: @nohillside Nope, still same issue. When I try to run rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.systempreferences.savedState with systemprefs open, it just enters a new terminal line. But when the sysprefs are opened, i've got this error  rm: /Users/hugo/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.systempreferences.savedState: No such file or directory

Comment: @nohillside I've found some sort of solution! I've updated the question with the video https://youtu.be/kapOvWY8xXE

Comment: Fascinating indeed. Can you right-click the "wrong" version in the Dock and select Options->Reveal in Finder? Curious where this is coming from.

Comment: @nohillside I've made a map in my main account for all the adobe apps. So here is the 'wrong' version placed. Apps > Mac apps. The correct one is in the Apps map as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I like to make a new user account and the log out of all the old users. No data is lost, but you can time the new user to open preferences.

Then you know if the problem is the system needs to be fixed / reinstalled or just your user has corrupt preferences.

Assuming it’s not your user account, this might be faster to sort by a Time Machine backup and erasing the mac to reinstall a clean OS. Once you’re sure it’s not a bug in a clean OS, you can run Migration Assistant and bring back your apps / documents and not your settings in the hopes that it cures the issue.

Sorry I don’t have a more surgical method to isolate this reliably. It’s hitting what might be an isolated issue with a big hammer, but you probably need a backup anyhow since the system is degrading and you’ll likely spend more time troubleshooting this than testing a clean install.

Comment: Thanks @Bmike for your response. I've made a new user (trough terminal), but it has the same problem.

Comment: @HugOnline Wonderful isolation - I’ll expand on my answer - my solution isn’t a great one - hopefully someone more skilled or with time to reproduce it could propose a more precise fix.

Comment: Thanks for the help and update @bmike. As u can see, I've updated the question, you can see there I somehow found a solution!